# why css class is not included in bundle css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I am using `postcss-purgecss` plugin to remove unused css file.I am facing one issue my one class is not `preserve` in bundle why ?

here is my configuration file

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
    [
      "postcss-preset-env",
      {
        "autoprefixer": {
          "flexbox": "no-2009"
        },
        "stage": 3,
        "features": {
          "custom-properties": false
        }
      }
    ],
    [
      "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
      {
        "content": [
          "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./src/pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./src/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./src/core/components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
        ],
        "safelist": [
         "body",
         "html",
         ".f20 [class^='icn-']:before,.f20 [class*=' icn-']"
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

why this class is not preserved `".f20 [class^='icn-']:before,.f20 [class*=' icn-']"` it should be present in bundle.

Steps to follow to check build

1. Close the terminal  and run `npm run build`.
2. It create `.next` folder inside this there is `static folder` inside there is `css` folder where you check the output

https://repl.it/@naveennsit/HorribleNumbAtom

[image]

any update ?